# Change touch input into mouse/keyboard input

Tags: c#, wpf, touch

Is there any way to transform a Touch input into mouse/keyboard input? Need the code for virtual touch pad.

Comment: By default, touch automatically translates to mouse and keyboard events. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: No it seems..., because when l use the `BlockInput` (which suppose to block all inputs), only inputs from keyboard and mouse are disabled. If Touch event are to be translated into mouse or keyboard, it will be disabled too. But it doesn't. So that's why l think there must be having a different solutions. Different code needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an ELO touch-screen you can turn it into a full digitizer so you pretty much get the real deal. Here the link to their [digitizer driver](http://www.elotouch.com/files/unrestricted_drivers/SW601073_EloWin7MTDriver1.1.1.exe), which works for W7/W8.

As for a virtual touch pad, I am not sure what code you are refering to.

Comment: Sorry, I read the question wrong... not sure what you want to do here.